# Add an additional axis with different ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot that plots iteration vs. progress for an optimization problem.  What I want to do is add an additional axis (at the top of the plot) that uses the same data - but also marks wall time.  Thus there are two x-axes in 1-to-1 correspondence with each other, on top and bottom, and one data series.  I've created the second axis as:

```
ax2 = ax.twiny()  
ax2.set_xlabel('Wall Time (s)')
```

But now I don't know how to add the new ticks.  I'm alternatively open to having two x-data series for each y series, but I don't know how to do this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xlabel('Wall Time (s)')
ax2.set_xlim(0.0, np.max(all_data, axis=0)[0] * scale_amt)
```

Comment: Or use secondary_axis